# Extract URLs from SMS

Tags: java, android, url, sms

What I want to achieve is to extract all the URLs contained in a SMS. When I mean all, I mean all the clickeable text, those that are underlined in the SMS. This is the code I'm trying and it works but only if the URL starts with http/https/ftp... and I need to get also the URLs without that.

```
public static List<String> extractUrls(String sms) {
    List<String> containedUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
    String text = sms;

    // Split the sms to analyze if each part is a URL
    String[] split = text.split(" ");

    // Attempt to convert each item into an URL
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(split[i])) containedUrls.add(split[i]);
    }

    return containedUrls;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Regex

```
public static List<String> extractUrls(String sms) {
List<String> containedUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
String text = sms;

// Split the sms to analyze if each part is a URL
String[] split = text.split(" ");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(@)?(href=')?(HREF=')?(HREF=\")?(href=\")?(http://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+(\\.\\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+)+(/[#&\\n\\-=?\\+\\%/\\.\\w]+)?");

// Attempt to convert each item into an URL
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if (p.matcher(split[i]).matches()) containedUrls.add(split[i]);
}

return containedUrls;
}
```